# Pandas: Can I group by entries of one column and sum its elements based on the entries of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following Dataframe

```
index =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
dct =  {'Unique household identifier': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2}, 'Relationship to head [Standardized version]': {0: 'Head', 1: 'Spou', 2: 'Son/', 3: 'Son/', 4: 'Son/', 5: 'Son/', 6: 'Head', 7: 'Spou', 8: 'Son/', 9: 'Son/'}}
R = pd.DataFrame( dct, index=index )
```

[image]

I would like to convert this DataFrame (Assuming it has lots of other columns). I am trying to make it look as

[image]

I tried coding this with a for loop and pivot table using the following code but did not work.

First one:

```
R.pivot(index='Unique household identifier', columns='Relationship to head [Standardized version]', values='Relationship to head [Standardized version]')
```

Second one:

```
B=[]
for i in range(1,len(R.columns)+1):
    A=R[(R['Unique household identifier']==i)*(R['Relationship to head [Standardized version]']!='Head')]['Relationship to head [Standardized version]'].value_counts()
    B.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[A.values],columns=A.index))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution may be `pd.crosstab`:

```
 res = pd.crosstab(index=R['Unique household identifier'], 
                   columns=R['Relationship to head [Standardized version]'])
 res.drop('Head', axis=1)

Relationship to head [Standardized version]  Son/  Spou
Unique household identifier                            
1                                               4     1
2                                               2     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but is it possible to take the entries of all the other columns of the DataFrame for this particular 'head' and included it in the model?

Comment: Thank you so much for this! but please keep the comment :)

Comment: I deleted it because your question changed from "the other DataFrames" to "the other columns". For context, I had written: `What do the other DataFrames look like? Maybe something like pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) would work`